# make multiple elements hover

Tags: html, css

I have three a tags inside a div all with hrefs

```css
.title {
    text-decoration: none !important;
    color: #000000;        
}

.title:hover{
    color: #f20d20;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <a class="title" href="google.com">title 1</a>   
    <a class="title" href="google.com">title 2</a>
    <a class="title" href="google.com">title 3</a>  
</div>
```

I would like it so that if the user hovers over one element all of them change hover color. Im sure this is a simple problem but i cant get it to work.

Answer (score 3):

Add Hover to the parent and color to the items:

```
div:hover title {
  color: #f20d20;
}
```

Comment: How about if titles have margins?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `div:hover`

You cannot select all siblings of an element. You can select titles followed by the hover title with `.title ~ .title` but for previous titles no way in css.

Answer (score -1):

Can you please check the below code? Hope it will work for you. Here I have added `display:inline-block` property to the parent div so that it does not cover the entire block on hover. Also added hover to the parent div and color to the links.

```css
div {
   display:inline-block;
}

.title {
    text-decoration: none !important;
    color: #000000;  
}

div:hover a{
    color: #f20d20;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <a class="title" href="google.com">title 1</a>   
    <a class="title" href="google.com">title 2</a>
    <a class="title" href="google.com">title 3</a>  
</div>
```